# Could you indicate me a PDF reader for android with a fit visible feature?

Tags: pdf, ebook-reader

Could you indicate me a PDF reader for android with a fit visible feature? It's the same feature that's built in on foxit reader.

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure about Foxit Reader, but I am using the paid [ezPDF Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=udk.android.reader).

I am really amazed about its ability to show and fit the content to screen when reading columns of text (like in newspaper). It has other super features like horizontal scroll and automatic scroll to next part.

Comment: ezPDF Reader in fact is the most recommended PDF Reader for Android. Other PDF readers worth a look include [RepliGo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cerience.reader.app) and [Aldiko](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aldiko.android), the latter being an eBook Reader with PDF support.

Answer (score 2):

I am not exactly sure what you mean by "the fit visible feature".

Give a try to [qPDF Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qoppa.activities.viewer), it's a free Android PDF Reader that does have a text reflow mode accessible (under View menu from the action bar).

A simple double tap fits the document to the screen size – which is pretty useful on tablets.

Answer (score 2):

Gustavo. I had similar problem. I am using [eBookdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ebookdroid&hl=en). It is free and it crops and splits pages. Good luck.

Comment: Please provide a link to the app. :)

Comment: Link added to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try [SmartQ Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartdevices.special&hl=fr)?

In my opinion it's the best PDF reader for Android. The interface is clean and intuitive, it has all main features that you are expecting from a eBook reader (Bookmarks, Pager, Chapters, etc..) and the transition between pages is very smooth and pleasant. And the most important in your case, the crop feature is so intuitive and practice. In my opinion it's the most comfortable eBook app you could find at this moment. I love it so much!!

Actually, I have been testing all eBooks apps available on Play store, keeping in mind the points I consider more important in this kind of app.

1) All basic features: Bookmarks, Pager, Chapters,

2) Interface + Page transitions

3) Crop feature

4) Read PDFs (I don't like ePub stuff)

Then here is my classifying of all I found meeting all these points:

1) [SmartQ Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartdevices.special&hl=fr)

2) ezPDF Reader - The problem with this app is that the transition behavior is not much pleasant as other apps, and sometimes you need to swipe 2,3 times to finally turn the page, which is very annoying (mainly when you cropped your pdf). And another little problem is that the crop feature, really crops the file. I mean when you open, then, the same file with another pdf reader, the file is also cropped as you have done it on ezPDF Reader! Which can be disrupting.

3) Moon+ Reader Pro - Interface much better than ezPDF Reader but less features too.. The crop feature is also available there but it's not very well designed. Plus when your file is cropped (actually is more fitted than cropped there), it becomes difficult to turn pages (a little bit as ezPDF Reader Pro)

4) EBookDroid - It works as expected but the interface and global user experience is very poor. It's not pleasant to use. By cons, the crop feature is very well imagined (much better than in Moon+ Reader Pro). I was not able to find if Chapters + Bookmarks feature are implemented. Sorry but it was so painful to test this app.

There is a last option, that requires two applications. This approach is the more constraining but you will have the best reading experience like that. Actually the really best PDF reader (in terms of interface, user experience, page transitions, etc..) now is Google Play Books (Since you can now add your own PDFs in this app by checking an option in settings). The problem is that app hasn't any crop feature, which is so annoying. So the main idea is to crop the file first with ezPDF Reader (Trial version it's enough), and then open it on Google Play Books app. Like this, you will have a wonderful reader experience thanks to Google app, and your PDF will be cropped as you want thanks to ezPDF Reader

*Sorry, I can't post more than two links, I wanted to link all apps mentioned there but I am sure you will find them by yourself..